# Having some trouble converting my regex to a SED statement

Tags: regex, sed

I have a document in which I need to strip out quotes and replace some of them with left parenthesis, others with right parenthesis, and others removed entirely. I need to pass some regex to SED, to replace...

This:

```
"/FIELDS=UPDATE_MODE"|"PRIMARYKEYVALUE"|"FLAG996"
C|000500099|"MBA6621,MKTG5505"
C|000500312|"SOWK5501,SOWK5510,SOWK5515,SOWK5520,SOWK5550,SOWK5571,SOWK5576,SOWK5577,SOWK5578,SOWK5579,SOWK5591,SOWK5594,SOWK6615"
C|000500675|"EDLA6614,EDLA6657,EDLA6657"
C|000500678|HI6540
C|000500811|"DENT6610,MPH6602"
```

Needs to become:

```
/FIELDS=UPDATE_MODE|PRIMARYKEYVALUE|FLAG996
C|000500099|(MBA6621,MKTG5505)
C|000500312|(SOWK5501,SOWK5510,SOWK5515,SOWK5520,SOWK5550,SOWK5571,SOWK5576,SOWK5577,SOWK5578,SOWK5579,SOWK5591,SOWK5594,SOWK6615"
C|000500675|"EDLA6614,EDLA6657,EDLA6657"
C|000500678|HI6540
C|000500811|"DENT6610,MPH6602"
```

My regex works:

```
^(C\|\d+)(\|)("{0,1})(([A-Z]|[0-9]{0,6},{0,1}){1,})("{0,1}$)
```

finds all all of the strings (ignoring the header)

```
$1$2($4)
```

replaces and adds the () in the appropriate positions.

But when I use this in SED like this:

```
s/^(C\|\d+)(\|)("{0,1})(([A-Z]|[0-9]{0,6},{0,1}){1,})("{0,1}$)/$1$2($4)/g
```

Nothing is replaced.

Does anyone have any help on this?

Comment: `sed` does not use Perl like regex syntax, only POSIX. No `\d` in the pattern, no `$n` in the replacement.

Comment: I do not think your regex works, see a [fixed regex demo](https://ideone.com/lI2le2).

Comment: Wiktor, you are correct. I had copied some of the code incorrectly.

Comment: Why is `"DENT6610,MPH6602"` not supposed to be replaced with `(DENT6610,MPH6602)`? `"MBA6621,MKTG5505"` is.

Comment: Wiktor, "DENT6610,MPH6602" IS supposed to be replaced with (DENT6610,MPH6602), but I had replaced "forward" in my working copy. My mistake.

Comment: But I'm still having trouble with this process. I am calling SED from BASH (or the command line presently). And I need to change the name of the input file. 

THE SED file is sedtest
The input file is export_short_flag996.csv
The output file is export_short4.csv

My sed code  in sedtest is:
```
s/"//g
s/(C\|[0-9]*)(\|)(([A-Z]|[0-9]{0,6},?)+)"?$/\1(\3)/
```
When I execute sedtest
sed -f sedtest export_short_flag996.csv > export_short4.csv

I get an error:
sed: file sedtest line 15: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Sorry, one question, one issue. Does my code solve your issue explained in the question?

Comment: If the replacement works in perl, you can just use `perl -pe 'replacement' file`